# What's are good Twitter PHP libs to send a message to new followers?

Tags: php, twitter, client, reply

I am looking for a good PHP based lib to send a message to new followers. Probably it's already done. I think it must work as a twitter client and not around OAUTH2 authentication.

Comment: Just so you know, I immediately unfollow anyone who does this. "Thanks for following" automated messages are lame.

Comment: Yes I know. But for big brands using twitter they can add promotional stuff when you follow them.

Comment: It's lame whether it's a small brand or a big brand. I don't see many big brands doing this - they likely know it's a turnoff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is Twitter's list of PHP API's

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php

You will have to use OAUTH2, otherwise you will not be able to send a message to followers.

Comment: That means that the user needs to log using a browser every time the software starts and/or after disconnections and other issues? I see that xAuth exists as an alternative but requires an approval.

Comment: No, OAuth doesn't mean you have to log in using a browser each time. Store the access token and keep using it.

Comment: There are clear OAuth expiration policies? or the access token remains the same for weeks or months?

Comment: In the twitter page it says that never expire: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554643/Authentication